# Integration With 3rd party - PreRequisites

Tags: integration

I am integrating SFDC with a 3rd party ERP Tool . As per various online articles these are initial steps which I understood :

1. Creating an Integration User.
2. SFDC Enterprise WSDL.
3. Creating a Global class  with details of what I want to query from 3rd Party.

Is this correct ?
Now,
1.My question is what all should I expect from the 3rd party?
2.If I want data in say 5 objects , what change does it demand from populating data in 1 object?

Comment: What is the requirement? Do you want to get data from third party system and update/insert in Salesforce ?

Comment: @C0DEPirate - Yes exactly .  Say I have 5 objects to insert/upsert data . Does the number of objects affect ?  What all should I ask from the 3rd party to start off the integration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are using SOAP API integration, you need to consume 3rd party WSDL in Salesforce.
2. It will automatically generate Apex code(Stub) for the WSDL that is consumed.
3. Write APEX classes to make callout.
4. You have to write triggers to perform insert/upsert based on the response you are getting from 3rd party.
   Other important things to consider:
5. Add the WebService end point to remote site settings
6. Try to make callout as asynchronous.

It seems you are a beginner, Salesforce Trailhead is an awesome learning tool about salesforce functionalities.

Try out this module : https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/apex_integration_services
  it will help you to get an understanding of integration.

Comment: @CODEPirate - I was reading something regarding certificates ? Couldn't understand where exactly do I need to provide that. Can you please provide some insights?

Comment: If you're calling out from SFDC -->3rd Party, you need to define a Remote Site.  Setup--> Security Controls --> Remote Site Settings.

Comment: Certs aren't really an issue unless you are trying to setup 2way SSL.

Comment: @BobbyWhite  So what I understand , before starting off , I need to ask the WSDL from the 3rd party and the Endpoint URL which I want to hit . Anything else which needs to  be taken care?

Comment: That's pretty much it.  1) You get the WSDL for the 3rd Party system.  2) You generate "stubs".  3) You define the Remote site.  4) you write a little custom Apex to call the stubs.

Comment: @BobbyWhite - Thank you . Can you please explain a little on what exactly does the WSDL contains . And a little more on the 4) point.  I am new to the web service concepts and it's hard to find documents in layman's terms.

Comment: HI@SFDCRookie Please avoid extended discussion here, if you have any particular query , ask a new question and community will be able to help you in a better way.

Comment: @SFDCRookie WSDL is a specialized XML document that defines the service.  Let's say you need to do something like validate an Address and get the GeoLocation for it.     You might use a service to do that and it might provide a method like    Validate(Address) --> Response contains {Address + GeoCode}  The WSDL would define both the structure of the information you need to supply to call it (request) and the structure of the data it will return (response) and the name of the service you need to invoke to do it.